# Only one of my site node's doesn't print it's alias

Tags: path-aliases

I use the latest version of the famous Pathauto module and my site pages have Automatic alias that are shown well in the URL navigation bar of the browser... All of these pages are in Hebrew, But one of the pages which is in English, doesn't show it's alias and only node/20 is being printed...

For example you could go on all main-menu links and see it, instead of that one...

[Here is a live example in my site](http://www.beniaharon.co.il/node/20).

What can cause it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the url alias pattern? (admin/config/search/path/patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments - I don't know what was the problem but re-creating the page (took about 40 seconds) fixed the problem.

Comment: that is really weird behaviour, but glad you finally got it to work

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to accomplish this, try:

- check the settings under /admin/config/search/path/settings and make sure the Update action is set to Create a new alias, Delete the old alias
- edit the node, and make sure the 'generate automatic URL alias' is checked and save the node again - this should reset the alias for the node

Comment: You are assuming right Geoff (edited the question) and indeed "Create a new..." is what check-marked in /admin/config/search/path/settings, and indeed, "Generate automatic..." is also check-marked in the node.

Comment: ok - check admin/config/search/path to see if that node already has an alias assigned to it - it could be that it's not checking and deleting an old alias and won't create the new one - I have had this happen a couple of times. If an alias already exists, delete it, and then resave the node

Comment: also, try running the bulk update for content

Comment: Actually there was an alias at the Aliases' list\log. Deleted it and resaved the node - didn't help. Afterwards I've tried to update the alias balk - also didn't help... Flush all caches after all of this was done btw, but I'm guessing it's yet another annoying RTLization problem...

Comment: I assume the english page is of the same content type as the others? is it only one page in english - if so, you could manually create an alias and change the menu entry so at least from a UI standpoint it worked, but if it's a gateway to other pages that don't alias properly that's not useful. I'm not sure what else to suggest, sorry

Comment: please either accept this answer or create a new answer with that information and accept that so the question does not remain listed as unanswered

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, using the alias itself in the menu-link item didn't help because this alias seems to not to be created (it appears in the aliases list\bulk but seem not the be recognized as an address in the site).

Comment: it sounds like a problem with the language. I did a search for 'Drupal 7 alias not working' and got a few pages with a lot of info on issues related to multi-language sites. I would look into that next